# How to find out a Windows 7 computer name from a debian?

Tags: windows, boot, debian

on a Laptop is a Windows 7 which is beyond repair - not booting anymore.

Booting from a USB drive with a debian system, how can I find out the Windows 7 computer name? (Normally shown on right click "Computer" Properties - but beyond repair)

Answer (score 1):

The computer name is stored in the registry files.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName

You will need a separate program to view registry files on Linux.

Comment: Thanks :) Used chntpw for viewing, CurrentControlSet is ControlSet001 on my machine.

Comment: @exalt If this answer answered your question, please mark it so that other users can find it.